# As a devoted LaTeX user, how do I most effectively use software which is *not* TeX-based?

Tags: conversion, best-practices, workflow

I realize that this question is heretical here and may even be off topic but I cannot think of another place to ask.

I am an enthusiastic LaTeX user.  I use it for even the briefest communications, yet after much wringing of hands and gnashing of teeth I have concluded that I cannot use LaTeX to prepare manuscripts for journals in my field (aquatic ecology and biogeochemistry).  Too few journals accept manuscripts written in LaTeX.  I have tried conversion tools (e.g., `latex2rtf`) but the amount of post processing often negates the utility (e.g., poor BibTeX support, poor math typesetting, major errors in tables, etc...).

So my question is how can I retain many of the advantages of LaTeX while composing documents that will ultimately need to be in `Word` (actually I use `Abiword`)?  The functionality I would like to maintain is:

- files stored as plain text
- files that can be edited by a text editor (mainly emacs)
- some type of automatic bibliography support (preferably open source)
- math typesetting capabilities

Comment: This question seems rather vague, but more importantly I'd say that if you need a final version in Word then you should use Word. That's certainly what I do for work (in chemistry).

Comment: Have you tried `tex4ht`? The documentation isn't very clear but it gives some good results

Comment: You can edit RTF files directly in Emacs.  Indeed, the syntax is not terribly different from LaTeX syntax -- braces for grouping, and control sequences to change formatting within a group.  If you just want to write something within your text editor of choice and then send it off to someone and say "Here, open this with Word," that might be your best bet.

Comment: Joseph Wright using Word for work is rather like Steven Spielberg directing sitcoms :)

Comment: @Ryan: How so? Isn't more like a plumber directing a Spielberg movie?

Comment: @JosephWright, that is an obvious solution but I am not ready to give in yet. Remember the Alamo!!!!  Also I work on a bunch of different computers (some pretty old) so I like to keep most of my files in plain text.

Comment: @DanVelleman I thought about that but there must be a reason no one seems to do that...  I mean the version of emacs I use doesn't even come with an `rtf-mode`.  That frightens me.

Comment: I got to thinking while looking into `tex4ht` (thanks @ienissei - that might be a solution), would writing directly in `html` be a viable option?

Comment: try `mk4ht oolatex yourfile.tex "" " -cunihtf -utf8"` this will generate document in `odt`format, which can be easily converted to word

Comment: Good question, I've actually been faced with a similar issue lately. I had a book chapter to write, and Springer politely informed me in the author instructions that I could use anything to write it, as long as it was Word. Or words to that effect. But I don't like word processors, I like markup.

Comment: @FaheemMitha thanks. I sympathize.  I added an answer myself because I have begun writing things that I know will likely need to be in Word in `html` markup.  Word just opens it and formats it without much fuss so it might be an option.  So far I am pretty happy with it as a solution.

Comment: @DQdlM: If you are directly writing in html, isn't that kind of clumsy? I was going to suggest switching to another markup language, but I didn't mention it because you seemed set on staying with TeX, which I can relate to. However, something like Docbook *might* be less painful to write in than html,  is certainly more high level, and is probably much easier to convert to Word than LaTeX. A quick Google shows http://www.explain.com.au/oss/docbook/index.html for example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look.  So far I have not found it to be too clumsy.  Although I did consider `markdown` as a possibility. I am not totally committed to LaTeX if something else would fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I have come to is to compose in `html`.

- `Word` (or clones) will open and parse `html` files so there is no need for file conversion.
- `html` files are text and can be edited with any text editor.
- I can use [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) to generate my literature cited in `html` from my BibTeX database.

  - This is not as efficient as using `\cite` because it needs to be created independent of the document but it can be relatively graceful if you just maintain a list of cited BibTeX keys.
- Math can be typeset into the `html` document using `MathJax` but this doesn't work well with `Word`.  In the end, `Word` math support is just lacking.
- Finally, generating a simple `css` file as an analog to a LaTeX style file will allow for relatively nice typesetting if I want to publish the document outside of `Word`, as the `html` can be converted to `pdf` using `wkhtmltopdf`.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend you check out the latest development version of Pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Pandoc allows you to write in Markdown or LaTeX and convert the output to a wide variety of formats. As of a couple of days ago John McFarlane, Pandoc's developer, added **support for Word docx output**. *This latest version even renders math using OMML* (Microsoft's Office Math Markup Language)!

Since this is the development version, you'll have to build pandoc from source. To do so you'll first need to install Haskell and associated build tools, which you can get for your platform of choice at http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/.

Once you've installed Haskell, follow these instructions on the Pandoc wiki:

[Installing Development version of Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc-1.9)

If you write in markdown, which has relatively light-weight markup (hence it's adoption for many sites like StackExchange!), you keep the option of outputting not only to Word, but also HTML, RTF, LaTeX, etc.

Comment: cool, thanks for the suggestion.  It's like the one ring!

Comment: It really is. It can also do citations and tables in markdown. It can also convert markdown to latex, with or without headers.

Comment: Also, @KennyPeanuts, since this is clearly a more broadly applicable answer than the selected one, you should choose this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like you, I use LaTeX when I can but use a word processor for journal manuscripts. Even if some journals accept LaTeX, their templates tend to be highly customized, and after a ms. rejection and faced with the task of weeding out all those proprietary macros I quickly abandoned that route.

I find OpenOffice (or now, rather, LibreOffice) Writer quite decent. I use it in conjunction with the Bibus reference manager, which I'm also quite pleased with. LibreOffice writes PDF, Word files (doc or docx) and also lets you export LaTeX. However, for LaTeX export I actually use the writer2latex tool, which lets you export with only minimal markup; the default built-in export produces lots of boilerplate code and clutter.

Math typesetting is good enough for what I need, but not great.